# Derivative and second derivative question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose the derivative of a function $f$ is below.  On what interval is $f$ increasing?

$$
f'(x) = (x+1)^4(x-5)^3(x-7)^6
$$

Comment: Where does the second derivative come in?

Comment: Why use the Second Derivative Test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test)?  The hint/answer provided below should answer your questions.

Answer (score 8):

$f(x)$ is increasing wherever $f'(x) > 0$. Thus, it follows that $f(x)$ is increasing wherever:

$$(x+1)^4 (x-5)^3 (x-7)^6 > 0$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

As Tards said:

$f(x)$ is increasing when $f'(x)>0$ which in my opinion should be well known in Calc I.

However, Tards did not answer the question in the form you desired so I will do that.

It is easy to see,

$(x+1)^4(x-5)^3(x-7)^6>0$ when,

$(x+1)^4>0$ which is equivalent to $x>-1$ so the interval is clearly:

$[-1,\infty]$

I know some people may comment and say that I divided the RHS by $((x-5)^3(x-7)^6)$ and if $x=5,7$ I would divide by zero. But if you plug in 5 or 7 it is clearly greater than -1.